# PHP Protected variables don't work for me

Tags: php, variables, protected

i'm having trouble with protected variables in PHP. Why doesn't work this code? It keeps showing me error 500. Here's the code:

```
<?php
class A
{
    protected $variable;
}

class B extends A
{
    $this->variable = 'A';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `$this->variable = 'A'` or add this statement at method.

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini.

Comment: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`  `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: `$this->variable = 'A';` needs to be in a method

Comment: @AdamForbis or re declared properly

Comment: @bassxzero that could also work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put instructions like attributions at body of class. Only members definitions are allow. Put the `$this->variable = 'A';` inside a method.

Change:

```
class B extends A
{
    $this->variable = 'A';
}
```

To:

```
class B extends A
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable = 'A';
    }
}
```

Comment: He can also re-declared the property.

Comment: @bassxzero why re-declare?

Comment: Because setting the variable value at run time might not be the behavior he wants. He may want a "default value" type of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your php code with the following:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

class A
{
    protected $variable;
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->variable = 'A';
    }
}

?>
```

It should resolve the issue and if there are any others give you more detailed information about what's going on.

Comment: He can also re-declared the property.

Comment: Also you're missing `function` on your constructor declaration.

Comment: @bassxzero He can also create a new class which doesn't extend A or use $variable in a different scope or not have a class at all.  I don't think providing the near infinite solutions to a problem is particularly useful/necessary.  Good catch with the lack of the function keyword though.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables should be used within methods or functions.

```
<?php
class A
{
    protected $variable;
}

class B extends A
{
    // Class variables need to be used within methods. 
    // For example: to set the value
    function ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        $this->variable = 'mysql:user;pwd:12345';
    }

    // or to return the value
    function output()
    {
        return $this->variable;
    }
}

$b = new B();

$b->connectToDatabase();

echo $b->output();
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac3171a98ccb901ca7cc8890659ca409a47fb30c